Error: Type '<T>(item: T) => T' is not assignable to type '(item: T) => V'
/** return self callback */
export function return_self_cb<T>(item: T): T {
  return item;
}

/** convert array to dict<key, item> */
export function array_2_dict<T, K extends string | number | symbol, V>(
    items: T[],
    get_key_cb: (item: T) => K,
    get_item_cb: (item: T) => V = return_self_cb
): Record<K, V> {
  const dict = {} as Record<K, V>;

  for (let item of items) {
    const key = get_key_cb(item);
    dict[key] = get_item_cb(item);
  }

  return dict;
}

vscode ts extension throws error indication in get_item_cb: (item: T) => V = return_self_cb:
Type '<T>(item: T) => T' is not assignable to type '(item: T) => V'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'V'.
    'V' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'.
(ts2322)

How can I solve this error indication?
I hope typescript can realize type V could be T also.
How to write a correct code to eliminate this error indication

It could be T, but it doesn't have to be, and someone could technically call array_2_dict with a manually specified V that doesn't work.  See the linked q/a for an explanation and approaches.  I'd probably just use a default generic type argument and a type assertion as shown in this playground link.
